# summarize variables from current row and its previous

Tags: sas

This is my input:

```
data a;
policy_no = 1;
X_NET_PREMIUM_AMT = 1;
X_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT = 8;
output;
policy_no = 1;
X_NET_PREMIUM_AMT = 2;
X_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT = 6;
output;
policy_no = 1;
X_NET_PREMIUM_AMT = 9;
X_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT = 4;
output;
policy_no = 1;
X_NET_PREMIUM_AMT = 12;
X_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT = 5;
output;
policy_no = 1;
X_NET_PREMIUM_AMT = 6;
X_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT = 3;
output;
policy_no = 2;
X_NET_PREMIUM_AMT = 18;
X_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT = 78;
output;
policy_no = 2;
X_NET_PREMIUM_AMT = 25;
X_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT = 16;
output;
policy_no = 2;
X_NET_PREMIUM_AMT = 91;
X_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT = 42;
output;
policy_no = 3;
X_NET_PREMIUM_AMT = 123;
X_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT = 52;
output;
policy_no = 3;
X_NET_PREMIUM_AMT = 4;
X_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT = 1;
output;
run;
```

What I need to do is for every policy_no:

```
X_NET_PREMIUM_AMT = X_NET_PREMIUM_AMT OF PREVIOUS ROW + X_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT OF CURRENT ROW.
```

So far - no problems.

What makes it difficult for me to do is,
I need the X_NET_PREMIUM_AMT to be updated for the next calculation,
I will explain:

row #1 (policy_no = 1):

```
X_NET_PREMIUM_AMT = 0(no previouse row) + 8 = 8;
```

row #2 (policy_no = 1):

```
X_NET_PREMIUM_AMT = 8 + 6 = 14;
```

row #3 (policy_no = 1):

```
X_NET_PREMIUM_AMT = 14 + 4 = 18;
```

And so on....

Unfortunately, 
I have no idea how to do this...

Would aprreciate your help

Comment: Now I'm not sure what you describe - you need sum of last row and previous two rows??

Comment: If you trying create a running total, use the `retain` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a cumulative sum of `X_NET_PREMIUM_AMT` per `policy_no`. Because overwriting your original variable is not a good idea I'll name the new variable `cumsum`.

```
data b;
set a;
by policy_no;
retain cumsum;
if first.policy_no then cumsum=X_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT; else cumsum=X_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT+cumsum;
run;
```

So when a different `policy_no` is encountered `cumsum` will be the same as `X_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT`, for the other rows of this `policy_no` it will be `X_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT+cumsum`. Your data has to be sorted by `policy_no` for this code which is the case here.

Comment: If this solution solved your problem you can accept it or upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

```
data out;
    set a;
    by policy_no;
OUT_X_NET_PREMIUM_AMT = sum(X_NET_PREMIUM_AMT, lag1(X_NET_PREMIUM_AMT));
OUT_X_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT = sum(X_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT, lag1(X_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT));
    if last.policy_no then output;
run;
```

Use lag1() function for that - returns previous value of variable.

Maybe you mean last 3 values:

```
OUT_X_NET_PREMIUM_AMT = sum(X_NET_PREMIUM_AMT, lag1(X_NET_PREMIUM_AMT), lag2(X_NET_PREMIUM_AMT));
OUT_X_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT = sum(X_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT, lag1(X_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT), lag2(X_NET_PREMIUM_V_AMT));
```